# Sorting integers in Bash Shell Script with command line arguments as arguments to the sort fn?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, command-line, command-line-arguments

My problem is how can I iterate through the command line arguments if the number of allowed arguments is a variable:

example:

```
./sort.sh n <n integers to sort>
./sort.sh 5 3 4 2 1 5
```

I tried iterating it through a for-loop and putting it in a .txt file for the sort function but that presents a problem since the delimiter, say i, accepts only constants.

Thanks. :D

Comment: Hello, below are answers that disregard $1 or the first argument which determines the size of the input. How can you sort the following arguments based on the first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the number of arguments. You can get it from within the script with `$#`.

And you don't need to loop through the arguments. Just pass them one per line to `sort -n`.

Something like: `printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll try this one. :D

Comment: @mouviciel, how about sorting the following arguments based on the first argument which determines the size of the input?

Comment: @ThisGuy - What if the first argument is not consistent with the number of the following arguments?

Comment: hi, what if you dont want a next line and just a space? how can you achieve that printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n? tried adding space but it didnt work

Comment: @WonderingCoder, you need to replace line breaks by spaces in the result of the whole command `printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n`. One way is to let `echo` do the job: `echo $(printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 2 4 3 1 5 | fmt -s -w 1 | sort -n
```

like this?

Comment: The number of integer arguments to sort is variable. It can be say, 10 integers. :D I need to parse it in some way. I tried $i and iterating through the i's but that didn't work.

Comment: But isn't it redundant, can't you just skip it? Or you can, of course `head -n $n` the fmt output. Or you can `for((i=0;i<$n;++i))` whatever you want.